# Mathematical Notation for Successors / Predecessors in a directed Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I have a directed graph with two sets, vertices and edges, $G=(V,E)$.

What is the mathematical correct notation for all the **successors** / **predecessors** of *a vertex*?

At the moment, for the direct successors I use the **out-neighborhood** $N^+(v)$ or simply $S_v$. Equivalent for the direct predecessors. Is this a good way to do this? And what is the way to do it, if I want also the successors' successors (and so on) in the result set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is out I would refer to the successors of $v$ as $N^{+}(v)$ and the predecessors of $v$ as $N^{-}(v)$. After all, successors is just a different word for out-neighborhood.

For the successors of the successors, I would use $N^{+}(N^{+}(v))$. You could shorthand it to to ${N^{+}}^{2}(v)$ or a different notation you define.

**Edit:** For the set of all successors of $v$ in graph $G$, i.e. the set of all vertices *reachable* from $v$, I've seen this set denoted as $R_{G}(v)$ or $R_{G}^{+}(v)$. The set of predecessors, i.e. the set of vertices that can reach $v$, is denoted $R_{G}^{-}(v)$.

Comment: Thanks :) But what about all the successors, never mind if it's a direct successor or a successor of a successor, or a successor of a successor of a successor? Isn't there a common or concise notation for that?

Comment: Isn't that just a (weakly) connected component?

Comment: Edited by answer. I've seen the set of all successors (or vertices reachable from $v$) denoted as $R_{G}(v)$.

Comment: The question rises if there is also something similar for predecessors.

Comment: After a quick Google search, it looks like $R_{G}^{+}(v)$ and $R_{G}^{-}(v)$ for successors and predecessors, respectively.

Comment: That looks good, thanks :) If you have any references from your Google Search, I would be really appreciated if you could link them here.

Comment: Here are two lecture notes:
* http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~mne/275/post25digr.pdf
* http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15210-s14/www/lectures/graphs.pdf